# remove question mark with .htaccess rewrite module

Tags: ee2, .htaccess

i want to remove  ? from url with .htaccess rewrite module.

```
http://example.com/?/test/downloads
```

in this url i want to remove **/?** .
 how to remove this any idea

i am using Query string in expression engine i think this is the reason so that this question mark comes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using query strings then removing the ? will stop the site working. The ? has a special meaning in URLs, what comes after it is the query string.

Comment: you mean manage with 1 thing either ? mark or query string right??

Comment: No. The ? is there because you are using query strings in EE. Why are you using them?

Comment: i am using it to upload image in channel with channel form.
if i use simple html file input type for this it's showing 

"The form you submitted contained the following errors

Decryption of form settings failed."

while submitting the form.